# String changing in function unexpectedly

Tags: c++

I was playing around with stacks to understand the concept and implementation better and I stumbled upon a weird bug. I'm passing a string into a function, breaking down the string into individual char's and adding them to a stack, but when I printed the stack it was not the data I entered.

I fixed the bug (I commented it out to recreate the error) but i'm curious as to why this was happening, the miss matched output was constant and never changed.

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bracketCheck(const std::string& s){
    Stack<char> stack;

    // this works as expected:

    /*for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); i++){
        stack.push(*i);
        cout << stack.top() << endl;
    }*/

    //this gives a jumbled outout: 

    for (auto i = s.front(); i != s.back(); i++){
        stack.push(i);
        cout << stack.top() << endl;
    }
}

void main(){
    string a = "stanley";
    bracketCheck(a);
    system("pause");
}
```

stack.h:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;
template<class T>

class Stack{
private:
    list<T> data_;
public:
    Stack(){}
    void push(const T& data){
        //v1
        data_.push_front(data);
    }
    T top() const{
        list<T>::const_iterator it = data_.begin();
        return *it;
    } 
};
```

the output i'm getting:

```
s
t
u
v
w
x
```

Comment: Try to replace `auto` with `std::string::iterator` if you want the compiler to explain you what is the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string::front()` function returns a reference to the actual character at the front of the string. By looping with `for (auto i = s.front(); i != s.back(); i++)`, you're actually incrementing the *contents* of the string itself, not looping over indices of the string.

Pretty hilarious, actually. You're *very* lucky that incrementing `s` 6 times ends up at `y`, which just so happens to be the last character of the string you actually use. So the break-condition of the for-loop (`i != s.back()`) just so happens to be met. Lucky break. If the string had been pretty much anything else, you'd get a much more nasty crash.

Answer (score 2):

String methods `front()` and `back()` returns references to first and last character of string (reference to char), your input string is 'stanley', now look at the ASCII code table, `s` is 115 in decimal, and y is `121` in decimal, you created for loop which printed all values in range [115,121).